# querying json column in sql with Laravel

Tags: mysql, json, laravel, mysql-json

Seofilter db table has json column named category_ids. I wanna query where value 
exists in json col.

And not querying all the row and get their jsoncol value then explode etc, I wanna do it with less query to server because of server loads.

for example [{60, 59, 57}] or [{55, 58, 60}] so 60 exists both of them.

Comment: Provide a proper table structure and example data on http://www,sqlfiddle.com.. Also share your MySQL version with `SELECT VERSION()`

Comment: "And not querying all the row and get their jsoncol value then explode etc, I wanna do it with less query to server because of server loads." Indexing JSON data is pretty limited in MySQL.. Because you can only index datatypes like a int, double, float or string with generated columns in MySQL.. You can't index a JSON array type an search it.

Comment: That's not valid JSON. Do you mean `[55, 58, 60]`?

Answer (score 2):

Laravel 5.6.24 includes `whereJsonContains()`:

```php
DB::table('seofilter')->whereJsonContains('category_id', 60)->get();
DB::table('seofilter')->whereJsonContains('category_id', [60, 61, ...])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a group of JSON manipulating and searching function i believe you are going to find what you want over here start with JSON_CONTAINS 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains 
which clearly fits the example you provided .